# Difference between 等待 and 等到

Tags: simplified-characters

I'm struggling to differentiate between the two. Can someone explain this? Perhaps include some example sentences too.

Comment: answer in dictionaries, e.g. bkrs: 等待 wait for; await等待继承遗产 wait for dead men's shoes; wait for a dead man's shoes
等待时机 await a favourable opportunity; wait for a chance; bide one's time
他在等待机会。 He is waiting for his opportunity.
等到：to wait until
by the time when (sth is ready etc) （表示时间条件） by the time; when:
等到他来，我便告诉他。 I'll tell him when he comes.
（等候到） wait until; wait till:
等到头发白 wait until one's hair turns white
我们要等到他来。 We shall wait until (till) he comes.
also find 100 samples for each in jukuu, and more in Line dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 等待 simply means "to wait"
>
> Example: **等待**黎明 (**Wait** for dawn)
>
> *you wait for something to happn*

等到 means "wait until" or "waited till" depend on the context.

> 1. **等到**: "**wait until**"
>
> Example: "**等到**太阳落山" (**Wait until** the sun goes down)
>
> *You keep waiting until something happen*

~

> 2. **等到** "**waited till**"
>
> Example: 等了三天，终于**等到**你回来了 (waited for three days, finally **waited till** you came back)
>
> *You have successfully waited till something to happen*

user17686 wrote:

> *Are there instances that 等待 & 等到 can be used interchangeably?*

No, 等待 and 等到 have different meanings.

- **等待**黎明 (**wait for** dawn)
- **等到**黎明 (**wait until** dawn)/ **等**到黎明(**waited** till dawn)

However, 等, 等待 and 等候 can be used interchangeably sometimes.

- **等**黎明, **等候**黎明 and **等待**黎明 all mean '**wait** for dawn'

Comment: Can you also put 等待 in a sentence too?  Are there instances that 等待 & 等到 can be used interchangeably?  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

"等待"
Waiting for someone or Waiting for something happened.
You still waiting~

"等到"
I finally wait for that person!
I finally wait until that happened!
You don't need to wait and You can take the next step!

Answer (score -1):

等候 means that you are greeting somebody or something, 等待 means you can do nothing except waiting，等到  means wait for person